# Does the method I use to make classes make a difference in the long run?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

It's a bit of a newbie question, but I was wondering what the best way of making a class would be. As far as I can tell, there are two ways of making a class in C# that will lead to different results. I can create a class in a new tab in visual basics. I do so by left clicking on the name of my project in the Solution Explorer >> Add >> Class.

Separately, I can create a class by using the key word "class", as shown in the following code:

```
class Person
{
    private void Walkthewalk()
    {...}

    private void Talkthetalk()
    {...}
}
```

The only visible differences that I have noticed are the using statements at the beginning of the class in the new tab as they can differ from the ones in the other tab and that the tab technique makes a new, separate "nameofclass.cs" file.

In the long run, though, will the result be different if I use one technique over another? Or will VS2012 simply compile the code in such a way that it will ultimately make no difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class file in C# is a text file. It does not matter how you create it - by adding a new class from a template, adding a blank text file and editing it, copying an existing file, or writing a file in a notepad, and adding it to a VS solution.

The only thing that matters is what you write in your class file. If you do not like a template, you can edit it, use a different template, or type in a file from scratch. The end result is going to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference how you create the class as long as its syntactically correct. 
You can do it manually or use productivity tools like Visual Studio or Resharper to help you, but the end result is the same. 
In fact you can write your entire program in notepad and have it work the same way...

If you get used to using productivity tools you may never want to do it manually, but that's a personal preference

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out that the only difference will be that the using will not come in class that you type. However it is a good practice in coding that classes remain in different files.